# How to get the windowbuilder zip file offline Installation?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I want to know what are the eclipse version will support the windowbuilder and its available online for online installation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At present, the chosen answer has become OBE (overcome by events -- obsolete).

In order to install WindowBuilder offline, you must download *one* of the code repositories listed below. ([discussion here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1086014/))

- For Eclipse Neon, Oxygen, Photon, 2018 & 2019 (versions 4.6 to 4.11) download an upgraded [WB repository](https://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/).

On the left side of the page, download "repository.zip" (click 'Show Directory Contents' if you don't see that.  It should show up.)

Unzip the download.

In Eclipse, select "Install New Software" (under the Help menu).

Click "Add.." to choose the new repository.
Click "Local...", "Browse For Folder" and select the unzipped "repository" folder, then click "OK".
Click the other "OK" (or "Add"), too.

Check the box next to "WindowBuilder".  (It should be in the large, open pane of the "Install" window.).  Then click "Next>" and all other affirmative options until done.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had to copy  the jar files in the repository/plugins folder to user/.p2/pool/plugins , because updater was failing to dl and extract the plugin files.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse Mars and Eclipse Neon supports windowbuilder (I only worked with them, but I suppose every version of Eclipse supports windowbuilder). If you download Eclipse Mars v2, you will have windowbuilder by default. For Eclipse Neon, you must download windowbuilder.

Here is the link where you can find windowbuilder. Just follow the instructions
http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Comment: @marklark the below answer too works fine..i followed the instructions after long time..do not delete the below answer.

Comment: @sathya, the answer is no longer below.  It's now the accepted answer.  :^)!